# How to setAtribute "disabled" for button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have the `complete button` disabled when the `edit button` is pressed.

Here is the render list function

```
function renderList() {
  // This resets the list innerHTML to the new list
  el.list.innerHTML = taskList.map(function (data, i) {
    return `<div class="task">
            <div class="task-content">
                <div class="task-set" data-id="${data.id}">
                <input class="new-task-created" value="${
                  data.taskNew
                }" readonly style="${data.textDecoration ? "text-decoration: line-through" : ""}"></input>
                <input class="due-date" type="date" value="${
                  data.taskDate
                }" readonly></input>
                <input class="due-time" type="time" value="${
                  data.taskTime
                }" readonly></input>
            </div>
    
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
                <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
                <button onclick="completeItem(event, ${i})" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
        </div>`
  });
disable()
el.input.value = "";
}
```

This is my attempt trying to set the attribute to disable to the `complete button` when the `edit button` is being pressed.

```
function disable(){
  let selectEdit = document.querySelector(".edit")
  let selectComplete = document.querySelector(".complete")
  
  if(selectEdit){
    selectComplete.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
  }
  else{
    selectComplete.removeAttribute("disabled")
  }
  // render list again because you've added a new entry
  renderList();
  
}
```

Am I doing the set Attribute wrong?

Just an update to the code: The edit button is not working. Below is the `complete function`. I am not sure if this is causing a conflict with the `disable function`

```
//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem(event, i) {
  const editEl = event.target.closest(".task");
  let taskUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".new-task-created");
  let dateUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-date");
  let timeUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-time");
  let editbtn = editEl.querySelector(".edit");

  if (editbtn.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "edit") {
    taskUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    dateUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    timeUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    taskUpdate.focus();

    editbtn.innerHTML = "Save";
  } else {
    taskUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    dateUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    timeUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    editbtn.innerHTML = "Edit";
    taskList[i] = {
      id: taskList[i].id,
      taskNew: taskUpdate.value,
      taskDate: dateUpdate.value,
      taskTime: timeUpdate.value,
    };
    // store the list on localstorage because data changed
    storeList();
    // render list again because you've added a new entry
    renderList();
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) requires two parameters: `name` and `value`

Comment: It has to be either `disabled="disabled"`, or `disabled=""`, or just omit the value and just have the attribute`disabled`. `"true"` is not a valid value for a boolean attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

I got the HTML element `let selectComplete = document.querySelector(".complete")` and added it to the `editItem function` and set the attribute of `selectComplete` to `selectComplete.setAttribute("disabled", "")`

The `editItem function` now looks like this:

```
//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem(event, i) {


  const editEl = event.target.closest(".task");
  let taskUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".new-task-created");
  let dateUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-date");
  let timeUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-time");
  let editbtn = editEl.querySelector(".edit");
 
  let selectComplete = document.querySelector(".complete")
  
  if (editbtn.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "edit") {
    taskUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    dateUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    timeUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
    taskUpdate.focus();

    //Set the disable for the complete button.
    selectComplete.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    editbtn.innerHTML = "Save";
  } else {
    taskUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    dateUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    timeUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    selectComplete.removeAttribute('disabled');
    editbtn.innerHTML = "Edit";
    taskList[i] = {
      id: taskList[i].id,
      taskNew: taskUpdate.value,
      taskDate: dateUpdate.value,
      taskTime: timeUpdate.value,
    };
    // store the list on localstorage because data changed
    storeList();
    // render list again because you've added a new entry
    renderList();
  }
}
```